# How to set up Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1 with jdk 10

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, installation

I have downloaded Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1 and also jdk 10, then I have also set up everything for jdk 10, but I have no idea how to set Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1 with jdk 10... although I have tried my best to search throughout the internet...

Can you guys teach me the steps how to finish this setup process?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to **Tools > Java Platforms**, click the **Add Platform...** button, then in the wizard navigate to your JDK 10 folder (i.e. the folder containing sub-folders such as **bin**, **conf**, **include**, etc). Once you have done that, the steps required to create a Java project using NetBeans 9.0 RC1 and JDK10 are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994385/2985643).

Answer (score 0):

you can see from here for windows

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html

Comment: But my one is for Java but not PHP

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Windows 10, netbeans64.exe would not start. Gave message box saying could not find Java 1.8 or higher.
Editing etc/netbeans.conf, solved issue, thus:
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"