# var keyword not reconized in JDK 10

Tags: java, netbeans, java-10

I have installed netbeans (Apache version) with JDK 10 successfully, but can't use `var` keyword in my project, It keep saying `cannot find symbol`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you set your project to target java 10 compatibility?

Comment: Actually, I use many versions of JDK, so yes, I did it this way `Source Package --> Properties --> Libraries --> Java Platform --> JDK 10 ` .

Comment: Can you please show a sample of your code? Remember that var can only be used for local variables with initializers, not class-level variables.

Comment: @DavidKoelle,
Just a simple code like `var numbers = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

Comment: @FSm Setting `Java Platform --> JDK 10` is necessary, but not sufficient. Also ensure that you have set `{project} --> Properties --> Sources --> Source/Binary Format --> JDK 10`. If it is set to any older JDK version you will get _"cannot find symbol"_.

Comment: @skomisa,
I did this one too, but still not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `var` keyword with **JDK 10** in NetBeans:

- Ensure that you are [running the latest version of Apache NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html).
- In NetBeans add **JDK 10** as a Java platform (**Tools > Java Platforms > Add Plaform...**). It is not necessary to make **JDK 10** the default.
- Create a simple Java application (**File > New Project... > Java > Java Application**) and declare a **var** variable (e.g. `var v = 7;`) within the `main()` method.
- Select the project node in the **Projects** pane, right click and select **Properties**.
- In the **Project Properties** window ensure that **Libraries > Java Platform** is set to **JDK 10**
- In the **Project Properties** window ensure that **Sources > Source/Binary Format** is set to **JDK 10**
- In the **Files** pane open the file **project.properties** (under the **nbproject** folder) and navigate to the lines for `javac.source` and `javac.target`. Verify that they both contain the value `10`.
- Press **Shift-F11** to clean and build the project.

If there is still a *"cannot find symbol"* error for the `var` declaration then there is something fundamentally wrong with the NetBeans installation, so update the OP with:

- The content of the **Output** window after doing the **Clean and Build**.
- The source being compiled.
- The settings for `javac.source` and `javac.target` in **project.properties**.
- The version information shown in the **Help > About** window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven project, make sure that maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target are all pointing to 10.

```
    <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```