# eclipse 4.9 giving compilation error on using java 10 var keyword

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using java 10 with eclipse-4.9 it giving me compilation error while using var keyword 
eg

```
    public class ConsumerTest {     
     public void test() {
        var a = new String();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Have you set the project Java Compiler Compliance level to allow Java 10?

Comment: yes i did it 10

Comment: Please show the whole java-file where `public void test()` is placed inside

Comment: @lino i posted whole java file

Comment: @ArunKumar , i guess it is a bug.

Comment: Try the [latest Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) (4.12)

Comment: verify `javac.source` and `javac.target` both contains 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var keyword not reconized in JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958353/var-keyword-not-reconized-in-jdk-10)

Comment: Have you tried compile and run in cmd?

Comment: Show us the 'Java Compiler' page of the Properties for your project.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov its working thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried with latest Eclipse (4.12). its working fine.